# Why does "10" == "0xa" evaluate to true, but "10" == "012" doesn't?

Tags: php

These days I discovered this weird code fragment `"10" == "0xa"` which evaluates to true. The best which I was able to find in the documentation was about [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php):

> a variable's type is determined by the context in which the variable is used

But I don't see any integer context in that code fragment. While asking around people seem to accept that as a feature. One explanation I'm hearing is that PHP will compare them as numbers. So I did some number comparison for some valid expressions of 10 (with PHP-5.6.5):

```
<?php
var_dump(
    0b1010, "10" == "0b1010", // false
    012,    "10" == "012",    // false
    0xa,    "10" == "0xa",    // true
    1E+1,   "10" == "1E+1",   // true
    1e1,    "10" == "1e1",    // true
    10.0,   "10" == "10.0",   // true
    +10,    "10" == "+10"     // true
);
```

Where is this behaviour documented in the manual?

**Edit:** Please understand that question in the context of the example code. This should emphasize the inconsistency between the binary and octal representation vs. the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PHP Docs reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

> If you compare a number with a string **or the comparison involves numerical strings**, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

(my emphasis)

**EDIT**

A numeric sting is one that will return a Boolean `true` from the [is_numeric()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function

> Finds whether the given variable is numeric. Numeric strings consist of optional sign, any number of digits, optional decimal part and optional exponential part. Thus +0123.45e6 is a valid numeric value. Hexadecimal (e.g. 0xf4c3b00c), Binary (e.g. 0b10100111001), Octal (e.g. 0777) notation is allowed too but only without sign, decimal and exponential part.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch Very loosely. For example, "10abcde" is still a numerical string, whereas "abcde10" is not.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch Yet in PHP's world, they do.

Comment: `"0b1010" ` is binary representation for decimal `10`; `"012"` is octal representation for decimal `10`

Comment: Sorry, that I'm not clear enough. The octal representation for 10 is 012. But `"012" == "10"` doesn't evaluate to true. The same goes for binary.

Comment: Well lperhaps you've found a bug then..... you asked for the doc references, and I've provided them, that's the documented behaviour.... if you feel that it's wrong, then the thing to do is raise a bug at http://bugs.php.net

Comment: FYI I was finally pointed to the [definition of "numeric string"](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/PHP-5.6/spec/05-types.md#the-string-type). And yes the current behaviour is a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69588) and both the definition and the behaviour do change in PHP-7.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch - Thanks for that update.... and well done for actually raising the bug, 99/100 people wouldn't bother